# AMPPS Virtualhost deosn't work

Tags: virtualhost, ampps

1. I update /etc/hosts and test the ping, the domain works;
2. I use ampps admin tool to add domain, and verify the modification as the content below.

> ```
> <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
> <Directory "/www/companyname">
> Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
> AllowOverride All
> Order deny,allow
> allow from All
> </Directory>
> ServerName local.companyname.com
> ServerAlias local.companyname.com
> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/www/companyname/cgi-bin/"
> DocumentRoot "/www/companyname"
> ErrorLog "/Applications/AMPPS/apache/logs/local.companyname.com.err"
> CustomLog "/Applications/AMPPS/apache/logs/local.companyname.com.log" combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

then I restart the AMPPS, but it still doesn't work. It would connect to the default 127.0.0.1 page not my '/www/companyname' page.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What happens when you go to the URL? FWIW, the `Directory` directive doesn’t seem to match the directory you’re giving in the `DocumentRoot` so anything you put there is probably getting ignored

Comment: @Pekka웃 okay, I see I would try it later :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 just let you know, I updated the directory and DocumentRoot, but it still on the default page.

Comment: What exactly happens when you call the URL?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I solved the issue due to the path conf, gonna post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due the default setting of AMPPS, you should create 'extra' folder under the AMPPS/conf folder, it is not the one under AMPPS/`apache/extra`, should be AMPPS/`conf/extra`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I have done a complete re-install and it still is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I had to add an "extra" folder directly beneath the Ampps directory.

```
Ampps/extra/
```

After that everything started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to add your virtual host to /etc/hosts file, eg:

> 127.0.0.1 example.com

unfortunately ampps doesn't make this

PS Don't forget to edit /etc/hosts as root user (eg sudo nano /etc/hosts)

Comment: They have added this in version 2.4 the latest version is 3.8. You might wanna update. [link](https://www.ampps.com/blog/category/news-announcement) Search for "host".

Also this is not the solution for me.

Comment: Agree. This still does not work